# Need .htaccess rewrite by referrer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have my images for every item stored in seperate folders, like this.

http://domain.com/upload/phones/2262/1.jpg

Now I want to redirect user using .htaccess if referrer is google to

http://domain.com/az/phones/item/2262/

Can anyony help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} google [NC] 
RewriteRule ^upload/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/[^.]+\.jpe?g$ /az/$1/item/$2/ [L,NC,R]
```

Just keep in mind that `HTTP_REFERER` header can be manipulated.

Comment: thanks, thank a lot,
but it's not worked for images named 1_small.jpg and 1_med.jpg

Comment: It should work for `1_small.jpg` since I am matching that part using `[^.]+\.jpe?g`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=galaxy+s4&client=ubuntu&hs=hBi&channel=fs&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=9V7zUpvVDeKWyAOT2oHABg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1440&bih=748#q=site:mobistore.az+1_small&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=TOK9jrO65q-leM%253A%3B5rM8rbZgb20CEM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.mobistore.az%252Fupload%252Fphones%252F2182%252F1_small.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.mobistore.az%252Faz%252Fphones%252Fcat%252F2%252F%3B120%3B120

Comment: oh, when I press ctrl+r it works. may be some cache problems.

Comment: Yes that due to caching since all the links worked fine for me.